# Query for not displaying repeated data

Tags: mysql

I have a data table that displayed to the client. Looks like this image:
[image: data table]

Did anyone know how to made the same word at "Unit" and "Year" not typed repeatedly if same? So the result is just like this:

```
No. --- Unit --- Year      --- Expense
1.  --- SDK1 --- 2016-2017     50000
2.  (spanned)    (spanned)     40000
3.  --- TKK1 --- 2014-2015     50000
4.  (spanned)    (spanned)     50000
5.  --- TKK1 --- 2014          50000
```

What I know for the query is group by, but it will made all the expense gone, just get 1 expense. Any clue/idea?

Comment: What output format? HTML?

Comment: Yes, I will output it as PHP HTML, but what query for that? or it's not the query but the HTML?

Comment: Hope this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555916/sql-replace-repeated-rows-with-null-values-while-preserving-number-of-rows

Comment: hello try distinct [http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx]

Comment: possible duplicate of [create html table with rowspan from mysql table with one query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179960/create-html-table-with-rowspan-from-mysql-table-with-one-query)

Comment: perfect, found it. thanks to DanMan, I've search that but none result at this forum. My bad, but thanks